# Installing and running an EOS mainnet node

Tags: eosjs, mainnet, single-node

The purpose of this installation is for me to be able to make /v1/chain/ mainnet API requests on a remote server that I have access to that won't disrupt mainnet itself. I tried using [**EOSNation/Blockmatrix's single mainnet node installer**](https://github.com/BlockMatrixNetwork/eos-mainnet) and ran into some problems. I'm not sure if the install failed due to incomplete syncing and/or if I have it configured incorrectly. I have no idea how to properly install, and then run the node with this scheme.

After a ~10 hour sync I ran into this error:

```
100% 4.99M=9h52m", "", "2019-04-16 22:44:27 (4.33 MB/s) - ‘blocks_backup.tar.gz’ saved [161655694957/161655694957]", "", "stop.sh: line 13: kill: (14543) - No such process", "tar: blocks/blocks.log: Wrote only 2560 of 10240 bytes", "tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors"], "stdout": "14543\nblocks/blocks.log", "stdout_lines": ["14543", "blocks/blocks.log"]}
        to retry, use: --limit @/root/eos-mainnet/management.retry

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************
<ServerIPRedacted>              : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

**Server info**:

```
Ubuntu 18.04 x64 / 16 GB Memory / 320 GB Disk + 250 GB

75G  blocks.log
151G blocks_backup.tar.gz

Filesystem 1G-blocks  Used  Available  Use%  Mounted on
/dev/vda1  310G       227G  84G        74%   /
```

ls -all /root/eos-mainnet = https://pastebin.com/raw/qc3k76i3

ls -all /opt/mainnet = https://pastebin.com/raw/QQqMKjyu

cat /opt/mainnet/config.ini = https://pastebin.com/raw/QALiyC6Q

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you ran out of disk space, the chain is getting large!

If you just want to test getting a node up and running, you could restore from a snapshot rather than using a blocks backup. With ansible, set up a node with:

```
ansible-playbook eos.yml
ansible-playbook mainnet.yml
```

Then follow the snapshot instructions from: https://eosnode.tools/snapshots

Comment: Thanks. I deployed a server with 620 GB and was able to unpack everything but ran into issues which I have thoroughly documented here: [https://pastebin.com/raw/038cyYuf](https://pastebin.com/raw/038cyYuf)

I also text walled the EOS Infra server (sorry!) - I've only lightly played with EOSIO to this point and hope this thread can serve as a reference point for people launching (or attempting to launch) full mainnet nodes.

Best,
Kevin